# How to override image transparency (flame)

Tags: flutter, flame

I am using flame and loading an image and trying to render the image without the background color:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Flame can't know what part of your image that is the background, you'll have to remove the background and replace it with transparency in a graphics editor first.